# LOLCODE String Parsing

Tags: lolcode

Suppose I have a string that takes the form `"## ##"` in `stdin` that I want to read in, e.g. `"15 16"`. That's simple enough:

```
I HAS A STRINGY
GIMMEH STRINGY
```

That grabs the whole line from `stdin` and stores it into the string—er, excuse me, *YARN*—called `STRINGY`.

How would I go about extracting the two integers in the string? I want to be able to store 15 and 16 each as an integer (LULZ I MEANS NUMBR).

Comment: If you downvote my question, could you please provide a constructive comment? Despite the silliness of LOLCODE, esoteric languages are a challenging way to practice coding techniques.

Comment: I updated answer, after receiving upvotes I checked it again and there's a bug in it - had to use `DIFFRINT` instead of `BOTH SAEM` for checking if you need to append a character.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer:**

You can't do this in LOLCODE 1.2.

**Long answer:**

As there are no `YARN` manipulation functions and no way to cast a `YARN` to something like a `BUKKIT` in the proposed 1.3 specification (whereupon which we could simulate a string as a `BUKKIT` of characters), it's not possible to extract numbers from a string like that.

Using just the 1.2 spec, we can still make this work, I guess...

Since string concatenation already exists in 1.2 as `SMOOSH ... MKAY`, you could, in theory, reserve variables `str01` through `str99`, and then...

```
IM IN YR readloop UPPIN YR throwawayvariable WILE BOTH OF NOT broken AN DIFFRINT currentyarn AN STRINGY
    str01, WTF?
        OMG "Z"
            str99 R str98
            str98 R str97
            str97 R str96
            ...
            str02 R str01
            str01 R ""
            GTFO
        OMG "Y"
            str01 R "Z";
            GTFO
        OMG "X"
            str01 R "Y";
            GTFO
        ...
        OMG "0"
            str01 R "1";
            GTFO
        OMG ""
            str01 R "0"
            GTFO
        OMGWTF
            I HAS A ERRORMSG
            ERRORMSG R SMOOSH "I DUNNO WAT U SAY, illegal character", str01 MKAY
            VISIBLE ERRORMSG
            broken R WIN
            GTFO
    OIC
    currentyarn R SMOOSH str01, str02, str03, str04, ..., str98, str99 MKAY
IM OUTTA YR readloop
```

Next, getting the NUMBRs...

```
NOT broken, O RLY? YA RLY
    yarnnumber R ""
    done R FAIL
    IM IN YR parseloop UPPIN YR otherthrowaway WILE NOT done
        EITHER OF BOTH SAEM str01 AN " " AN BOTH SAEM str01 AN "", O RLY? YA RLY
            number1 R 0
            DIFFRINT yarnnumber AN "", O RLY? YA RLY
                number1 R MAEK yarnnumber A NUMBR
            OIC
            done R WIN
        MEBBE DIFFRINT str01 AN ""
            yarnnumber R SMOOSH yarnnumber, str01 MKAY
        OIC
        str01 R str02
        str02 R str03
        str03 R str04
        ...
        str98 R str99
        str99 R ""
    IM OUTTA YR parseloop

    yarnnumber R ""
    done R FAIL
    IM IN YR parseloop2 UPPIN YR otherthrowaway2 WILE NOT done
        EITHER OF BOTH SAEM str01 AN " " AN BOTH SAEM str01 AN "", O RLY? YA RLY
            number2 R 0
            DIFFRINT yarnnumber AN "", O RLY? YA RLY
                number2 R MAEK yarnnumber A NUMBR
            OIC
            done R WIN
        MEBBE DIFFRINT str01 AN ""
            yarnnumber R SMOOSH yarnnumber, str01 MKAY
        OIC
        str01 R str02
        str02 R str03
        str03 R str04
        ...
        str98 R str99
        str99 R ""
    IM OUTTA YR parseloop2
OIC
```

And lastly, what ever you wanted to do with them.

```
I HAZ A result
result R SUM OF number1 AN number2
VISIBLE result
```

For `...`, fill in the remaining statements that make use of the `str##` variables.

If you're gonna use this, I recommend using something to generate the LOLCODE for you, writing this by hand is just not feasible. Especially if you have to support longer input lines like 255 or 1024 characters.